# C#. Image.GetThumbnailImage aumentando o tamanho do arquivo

Tags: c#, imagem

Tenho uma imagem de 320x320.

Quando eu uso o `Image.GetThumbnailImage` ele gera uma imagem de 180x180.

Só que o tamanho do arquivo de 320x300 é 10k, o tamanho do arquivo do Thumbnail é de 52k...

Queria que ele fosse pelo menos igual, alguem tem alguma sugestão?

EDIT:

Eu tenho uma imagem no disco e abro ela assim:

```
Image image = new Bitmap(caminhoenomenodisco);
```

Depois disso eu simplesmente faço o Thumbnail assim:

```
Image nova = image.GetThumbnailImage(180, 180, null, new IntPtr());
```

EDIT:

Realmente a imagem do disco está com 24 de intensidade de bits e a nova imagem é salva com 32 de intensidade.

Não sei como gerar o Thumbnail com 24 de intensidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profundidade de bits deve estar diferente. O padrão do Windows (atualmente) é 32 bits.

Abra o `Bitmap` [especificando uma profundidade de bits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(320, 320, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

`Format24bppRbg` especifica 24 bits de profundidade. [Veja aqui a lista completa de formatos disponíveis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

A profundidade (ou intensidade) de bits pode ser vista nas propriedades do arquivo (botão direito > Propriedades), aba **Detalhes**:

[image: Bit Depth]

Para o seu caso em específico, é preciso recodificar o arquivo para outra profundidade de bits. Isto se faz usando um [`Encoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder(v=vs.110).aspx) do tipo [`ColorDepth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.colordepth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Neste último link há um exemplo que altero abaixo para refletir sua realidade:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
class Example_SetColorDepth
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        Encoder myEncoder;
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;

        // Abre o Bitmap
        myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\meubmp.bmp");

        // Cria um objeto para o Encoder baseado no MIME type
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/bmp");

        // Cria o Encoder propriamente dito
        myEncoder = Encoder.ColorDepth;

        // Parametrização
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Processo de conversão de profundidade de pixels
        myEncoderParameter =
            new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 24L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        myBitmap.Save("meubmp_24bits.bmp", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for(j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if(encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[A lista completa de tipos MIME está aqui](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/).

Comment: fiz uma alteração na pergunta, não entendi como eu posso abrir um arquivo em disco passando a profundidade de bits, os arquivos que tenho são 24 de intensidade sim. Como eu faria isso no código que editei na pergunta?

Comment: @user3517631 Editei a resposta.